# Convert excel to csv using sas script. excel has only one column

Tags: excel, sas, sas-macro

I'm super new to SAS scripting and I need to convert an excel with one column to a csv file.
Also I need to create new file with the input parameter appended in the name.
input file: price_levels.xls
output file: price.levels.210212

210212 will be passed as input parameter with script calling.

**some ideas got from internet:**

**IMPORTING EXCEL FILES INTO SAS**

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=WORK.sample
        DATAFILE="C:/mydata/Sample Data.xlsx"
        DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
    RANGE="Sheet1$";
    GETNAMES=YES;
    MIXED=YES;
    SCANTEXT=YES;
    USEDATE=YES;
    SCANTIME=YES;
```

**how-to-export-sas-data-as-a-csv-file/**

```
proc export data=work.my_data
    outfile="/folders/myfolders/export/cars.csv"
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-macros-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro variable in your code or you can use it directly in the code.
Double quotes are required for macro variables to resolve correctly.

```
%let report_date=%sysfunc(today(), yymmddn8.);

proc export data=work.my_data
outfile="/home/reeza/price.levels.&report_date..csv"
dbms=csv
replace;
run;
```

or direct usage:

```
proc export data=work.my_data
outfile="/home/reeza/price.levels.%sysfunc(today(), yymmddn8.).csv"
dbms=csv
replace;
run;
```

*Note the folders/myfolders structure is no longer relevant as SAS UE is deprecated.